AWS ALB Listeners & Target Groups
I am running 3 instances behind an application load balancer. I am trying to set up endpoints so when you access the ALB for example on the /ui endpoint, it will forward you to the appropriate target group, which is working on port 5001 for example.
But I think I have misunderstood how this works, because when I access the ALB without any endpoint, it works, but on the /ui/ endpoint, it does not.
I still do not fully understand where the issue is, and would like some guidance on the best way to configure the endpoints.
The destination applications do not have a /ui or /grafana endpoints for example. Is it necessary that they do? I thought the endpoints are strictly for the ALB's reference.
ALB.TF
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "trading-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
  subnets            = module.vpc.public_subnets

  tags = merge(local.tags, { Name = "${local.tags.Environment}-alb" })
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.app_ui_target_group.arn
  }
}


# Rule for Application UI on /ui
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "app_ui_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.app_ui_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/ui/*"]
    }
  }
}

# Rule for Stock Metrics on /metrics
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "stock_metrics_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 110

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.stock_metrics_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/metrics/*"]
    }
  }
}

# Rule for Mongo Express on /mongo-express
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "mongo_express_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 120

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mongo_express_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/mongo-express/*"]
    }
  }
}

# Rule for Promtail on /promtail
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "promtail_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 130

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.promtail_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/promtail/*"]
    }
  }
}

# Rule for Loki on /loki
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "loki_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 140

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.loki_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/loki/*"]
    }
  }
}

# Rule for Prometheus on /prometheus
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "prometheus_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 150

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.prometheus_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/prometheus/*"]
    }
  }
}

# Rule for Grafana on /grafana
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "grafana_rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority     = 160

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.grafana_target_group.arn
  }

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/grafana/*"]
    }
  }
}

TARGET-GROUPS.TF
# Target Group for Application UI on port 5001
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "app_ui_target_group" {
  name     = "app-ui-target-group"
  port     = 5001
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

# Target Group for Stock Metrics on port 8000
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "stock_metrics_target_group" {
  name     = "stock-metrics-target-group"
  port     = 8000
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

# Target Group for Mongo Express on port 8081
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "mongo_express_target_group" {
  name     = "mongo-express-target-group"
  port     = 8081
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

# Target Group for Promtail on port 9080
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "promtail_target_group" {
  name     = "promtail-target-group"
  port     = 9080
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

# Target Group for Loki on port 3100
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "loki_target_group" {
  name     = "loki-target-group"
  port     = 3100
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

# Target Group for Prometheus on port 9090
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "prometheus_target_group" {
  name     = "prometheus-target-group"
  port     = 9090
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

# Target Group for Grafana on port 3000
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "grafana_target_group" {
  name     = "grafana-target-group"
  port     = 3000
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    interval            = 30
    timeout             = 5
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

I tried setting the endpoints as mentioned above and that did not work. When I changed the mongo-express' listener rule to listen on "/" for example, the ALB forwarded me to the mongo-express instance, so I am pretty sure the instances are all healthy. The issue lays somewhere in the endpoints/target groups configuration I'm pretty sure.

The load balancer doesn't strip the path from the request, it forwards the path as-is. So for example any requests to /ui/whatever are going to go to the UI service, with /ui/whatever intact. The server has to expect to get requests with the /ui/ part of the path included. I think you have just sort of made-up a bunch of paths, without configuring each of your services to actually handle requests at those different paths.

If that isn't it, then please describe in more detail exactly what you mean when you say it isn't working.

@MarkB Hey Mark, so I did indeed misunderstood how the paths work here. I do not have these actual paths in my applications. To give you the general idea, my idea was to have an ALB infront of multiple instances. Going to ALB.COM/UI, would take you to the instance running the UI. Going to ALB/Grafana, would take you to the Grafana UI. I wanted to use these paths, instead of specifying the ports and have the ALB forward to the correct instance according to ports. In your experience, what's the best way to tackle this? Do I revert back to working with ports directly in the URL?

An Application Load Balancer can't do what you want with paths. You could try using CloudFront with multiple origins, and Lambda@edge functions to rewrite the origin URLs to remove the paths. Or you could try something like placing Nginx in front of everything, and having it rewrite the paths. Or you could just go back to using ports in your URLs.
